# why array subscript is above array bounds [-Warry-bounds] ? what should i do?

Tags: c, arrays, console

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char name[100],stdid[100],adv[100],subject[6][100],code[6][30];
    int sem,in,total,a;
    int credit[6];

    printf ("SUBJECT REGISTRATION FORM \n \n");

    printf ("1) STUDENT NAME: ");
    fflush (stdin);
    gets (name);

    printf ("2) STUDENT ID: ");
    scanf ("%s",&stdid);

    printf ("3) SEMESTER: ");
    scanf ("%d",&sem);

    printf ("4) ACADEMIC ADVISOR: ");
    fflush (stdin);
    gets (adv);


    for (in=0; in<6 ;in++)
    {
        printf ("SUBJECT CODE %d: ",in + 1);
        fflush (stdin);
        gets (code[in]);

        printf ("SUBJECT NAME %d: ",in + 1);
        fflush (stdin);
        gets (subject[in]);

        printf ("SUBJECT CREDIT %d: ",in + 1);
        fflush (stdin);
        scanf ("%d",&credit[in]);

        total=total+credit[in];
    }

    printf ("                       Universiti of Gambang \n");
    printf ("                     Subjects Registration Form \n");
    printf     ("======================================================================= \n");

    printf ("Name: %s \n",name);
    printf ("Student ID: %s \n",stdid);
    printf ("Total Subjects: %d \n",in);

    printf ("---------------------------------------------------------------    --------- \n");

    printf ("Subject Name                Subject code                              Credit \n");

    for (a=0;a<in;a++);

    {
        printf (" %d %s                           %s                                     %d        \n",a ,subject[a] ,code[a] ,credit[a]);
    }

    printf ("Total Credit:                                                              %d        \n",total);

    printf ("Academic Advisor: %s \n",adv);

    return 0;
}
```

Why don't my other outputs below the subject and code does not appear correctly? I think it suppose to come out 6 output on all tables. plus, from where does the 122 below credit come from?

[image] I am new in c. please help me.

Comment: Weird behavior often comes from undefined behavior caused by wrong memory manipulation. If you're experiencing **access violation** (segmentation fault), please try tools like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org) or [AddressSanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html) to determine the root of the problem.

Comment: `for (a=0;a<in;a++);` → `for (a=0;a<in;a++)`, `int sem,in,total,a;` → `int sem,in,total = 0,a;`. BTW, never use `gets`. It has been obsolete in newer versions of C due to its buffer overflow vulnerability. Also, `fflush(stdin)` invokes Undefined Behavior, as per the standards, although some implementations have defined behavior. But it is best to avoid it so that your code is portable.

Comment: thank you @CoolGuy .okay. i'll keep that in mind. :D